# Get Custom Taxonomy Title by Spesific Sub Category via fputcsv

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I had all posts under different Sub-Categories (taxonomy is 'category' / default WP) within one Category and also under Custom Taxonomy (taxonomy is 'program') something like this:

```
- Parent Category 1
- Parent Category 2 (*only this Category that have Custom Taxonomy)
-- Sub-Category A
--- Program v
--- Program w
-- Sub-Category B
--- Program x
--- Program y
- Parent Category 3
```

And I want to get the tittle of Custom Taxonomy ('Program v', 'Program w', 'Program x', etc...) for each posts and then send it via fputcsv function.

For current code as below, I can get the results as expected but it also display the title of Custom Taxonomy (in this case: 'Program v') that should have an empty object (from Sub-Category A) below new row too:

```
    Post     |  Category  |  Sub-Category  |  Program
Post Title 1 | Category 2*| Sub-Category B | Program x
Post Title 2 | Category 2*| Sub-Category A | Program v
Post Title 3 | Category 3 |                | Program v
Post Title 4 | Category 1 |                | Program v
```

Desired output in csv by using fputcsv is something like this:

```
    Post     |  Category  |  Sub-Category  |  Program
Post Title 1 | Category 2*| Sub-Category B | Program x
Post Title 2 | Category 2*| Sub-Category A | Program v
Post Title 3 | Category 3 |                | 
Post Title 4 | Category 1 |                |
```

This is the current code:

```
foreach ($arr_post as $post)
{   
    $idpost = $post->ID;

    $catList = get_the_category();
    foreach($catList as $cat)
    {
        if ($cat->category_parent == 0)
        {
            $maincatList = $cat->cat_name;
        }
    }

    $subcats = get_the_category($query->$idpost);
    foreach($subcats as $subcat)
    {
        if (!empty($subcats))
        {
            $subcatList = $subcats[1]->cat_name;
        }
    }

    $progrs = get_the_terms($query->$idpost, 'program');
    foreach($progrs as $progr)
    {
        if (!empty($progrs))
        {
            $progList = $progr->name;
        }
    }

    setup_postdata($post);

    fputcsv($file, array_map("utf8_decode",
        array(
            get_the_title(), 
            $maincatList, 
            $subcatList, 
            $progList, 
        )
    ));
}
```